# What BibTeX style generates inline refs like [1] AND displays URL in the references list?

Tags: bibtex, urls

All the styles I tested either:

1. Display [Author (Year)] inline, and with URL in the ref list; or
2. Display [1] inline, but no URL in the ref list.

Is there a style that displayes [1] inline AND provides the url at the ref list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of citation call-outs is affected by the chosen bibliography style only if no citation management package is in use. Which citation management package, if any, are you working with?

If you're working with the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) package, try loading it with the options `numbers` and `square`. I.e., type

```
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
```

in the preamble.